# why exist a difference between appending lists and vectors?

Tags: r, list, vector

My question is why the following code

```
list1 <- list()
list1[[1]] <- c()
list1[[1]] <- c(list1[[1]], 7)
```

shows the error

> Error in list1[[1]] : subscript out of bounds

and why the following code

```
vector1 <- c()
vector1 <- c(vector1, 7)
```

works? I want to do something like this

```
for (i in c(1,2,3)){
  for (j in c(1,2,3)){
    list1[[i]].append(list3[[i]], j)
  }
}
```

Comment: An option is `list1 <- vector('list', 1)`

Comment: The question isn't very clear. In any event, neither lists nor vectors are optimized for appending. That is an `O(n)` operation in R, which makes loops that build up a list/vector by appending quadratic in complexity. Much better to preallocate.

Comment: akrun and John Coleman thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like that ?

**Using for loop**
You can append numbers to each vector of a list by doing this:

```r
list1 = vector("list",3)
for(i in 1:3)
{
  for(j in 1:3)
  {
    list1[[i]] = c(list1[[i]],j)
  }
}
```

And you get the following output:

```r
> list1
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

**Using lapply**

You can do the same thing without the need to use `for` loop but instead `lapply`

```r
list3 = vector("list",3)
list3 = lapply(list3,function(x){1:3})
```

and you get a similar output